# Django object lookups in templates

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I am going through the Django project tutorial, and in [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/#use-the-template-system) section it says:

> The template system uses dot-lookup syntax to access variable
>   attributes. In the example of {{ question.question_text }}, first
>   Django does a dictionary lookup on the object question. Failing that,
>   it tries an attribute lookup – which works, in this case. If attribute
>   lookup had failed, it would’ve tried a list-index lookup.

Does this mean that the Django `question` is a dictionary object, and in the first instance, looks for `question_text` as the key, and if found, returns the value? Beyond this, I can't visualise what the two fall-back options are doing.

Comment: question is not a dictionary. When processing the template, Django only first assumes it is a dictionary. If it appears not to be, it will continue to check if it might be an object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does this mean that the Django `question` is a dictionary object, and in the first instance, looks for `question_text` as the key, and if found, returns the value? Beyond this, I can't visualise what the two fall-back options are doing.

`question` doesn't have to be a literal `dict` for the first option to work. It needs to be dictionary-like. That is, `question['question_text']` works in Python.

The first fallback refers to regular Python dot notation. For example, if either of these works in Python:

```
question.question_text  # or
question.question_text()
```

then `question.question_text` will work in the template returning the Python value. Note that parentheses are omitted in both cases.

The final fallback is numeric indexing. For example, if `question` is a list and this works in Python:

```
question[0]
```

then `question.0` will work in the template, returning the value of `question[0]`.